# Limiting the number of checkboxes selected by user on click

Tags: javascript, cakephp

We have some check boxes which correspond to different categories. We want to restrict the user to checking only 3 check boxes at a time, so I have set an alert for when more than 3 categories are checked.

```
<?php 
$countC = 0;
$count = 0; 
foreach($fcategories as $fvalue) {?>
<label>
<input class="group1" type="checkbox" name="catCheck[]" onclick="chkcontrol(<?php e($count)?>);" value="<?php e($fvalue['Qna_category']['id']);?>" ></input>
<?php e($fvalue['Qna_category']['category']);?></label><br/><?php $count++; }?>
```

And the function `chkcontrol()`;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chkcontrol(count) {
    var msg= '';
    var done = false;
    if(count >= 3) {
        msg = "Maximum 3 categories"
        done = true;
    }
    if(done) {
        alert(msg);
    return ;
    }
}
</script>
```

My problem is that alert popup opens, but it doesn't remove the 4th clicked check box & also do anything to stop the user from checking more than 3 boxes apart from a message popup.

Comment: You're hard coding count into the onclick attribute rather than calculating it. This means you'll only ever be able to check the first 3. Are you using jQuery or just native javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little inconvenient right now. To stop the select from happening you need to `event.preventDefault()` on the onclick event but as it is your `count` parameter takes the place of the event argument.

A workaround is to uncheck it:

```
if (count >= 3) {
    this.setAttribute("checked", "");
}
```

---

Mixing PHP and JavaScript generally gives you inconvenient code. It's better to serialize any relevant state you had in PHP to JavaScript, like:

```
var num_selected = <?php echo json_encode($count);?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but above code not working means after click ok on popup check box are still in checked form